# Disabling wifi in android programmatically

Tags: android

I am working on an application that changes wifi  programmatically.
what are the permissions i need to change in the menifest  please help

Comment: Be clear what you are trying to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review this help topic: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Then add this code in your java file.
you need to add two buttons,one for enabling and one for disabling.

```
final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    enableWifi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
            {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(LogTest.this,"Wifi Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    disableWifi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(LogTest.this,"Wifi Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Use the following to check if it's enabled or not

```
boolean wifiEnabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
```

Answer (score 2):

For people trying this on Android 10 and above, `setWifiEnabled` has been disabled. Refer [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#setWifiEnabled(boolean))